# Is there a way to directly convert cv::MatExpr to cv::Point in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

Let us assume I want to convert the result of a projection using matrix multiplication back to point because it is semantically sensible to do:

```
Point3f p_prim = A * p;
```

This, however, does not seem to work, since the result of the matrix multiplication is of the type `cv::MatExpr` and there does not seem to be a way to convert from `cv::MatExpr` to `Point`, or am I overlooking it in the OpenCV documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MatExpr` is convertible only to `Mat`. You can build your point like:

```
Mat1f temp = A * p;
Point3f pt(temp(0), temp(1), temp(2));
```

Assuming that the result of `A * p` is a `1x3` or `3x1` matrix.

Comment: This seems to be the most straight forward way to do it. I'm still wondering why this is not directly supported by the framework. Are `Point` and `Vector` not meant to be used this way? If so, what are they for?

Comment: With regards to OpenCV `Mat`, `Point`s are for matrix coordinates, `Vec_<Tp>` is an element of the matrix.